# Does Revolution kill ticks?

Tags: rabbits, medicines, fleas, pest-control, ticks

We have been using Revolution on our house rabbits for years, and I always assumed it killed ticks as well. Recently, someone told me it is not effective against ticks.

I know it effective against a number of parasites, both internal and external.

Does Revolution kill ticks?

Comment: I think that they only claim that it works on American Dog Ticks to cover themselves from liability associated with Lyme disease. My family just got back from a heavily wooded area where ticks are a problem. Our dog picked up several ticks that I discovered while giving him a flea/tick bath two days later. The ticks were still attached but already dead. He had both Deer and Lone Star ticks on him.

Comment: I also have been buying revolution and assumed my dog was protected from ticks and fleas. Not impressed .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and No.

> Revolution (Selamectin) controls tick infestations **only due to the American Dog Tick** (Dermacentor variabilis), a tick commonly found on dogs. There are other common species of ticks that are not killed or controlled by REVOLUTION. Your veterinarian can recommend appropriate products to control or kill ticks common to your area. [Source](https://www.zoetisus.com/contact/pages/product_information/revolution.aspx)

But...

> It’s not effective against the deer tick that causes Lyme disease. [source](https://parade.com/39758/parade/revolution-for-cats/)

So yes, it kills some, but not all ticks.

Comment: Link to first source does not work anymore, alternative source [is this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selamectin).

Answer (score 4):

This post is several years old but I will update it to add that there is now Revolution Plus which includes an additional active ingredient specifically targeting ticks. This might already be common knowledge to many or most pet people but hopefully will help anyone searching this information.