# How to kill ticks on a Rabbit?

Tags: rabbits, fleas, ticks

Having just learned that my rabbits flea treatment is [not effective on most ticks](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17582/does-revolution-kill-ticks) I am wondering what options there are for killing and/or controlling ticks on my pet rabbit.  I know there are several products you should [not use on a rabbit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925/how-do-i-get-rid-of-fleas-on-my-rabbit/1016#1016)

Our rabbits live in our home, sleep on our beds and go places with us.  When we go camping they come along.  Outside in the morning and evening for fresh grass, and in bed with us in the camper at night.  We have been doing this for years and have never had a flea, tick or parasite problem.  There are usually wild rabbits in the places we camp, so there are lots of opportunities to become infect.  Not sure if we have just been lucky or what.

What are my options for preventing and controlling ticks on rabbits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can only speak for dogs and cats, but it's basically the same:

**Remove them physically.** (Just check after there was a chance to pick some up and possibly 1-2 hours later.)

Get a **flea comb** to remove loose ticks from the fur and a **tick hook** to safely remove feeding ticks. I prefer tools to pull (and optionally twist) rather than pliers as it's far less likely you squeeze the ticks and you'll get them in one piece.

Be careful when handling the ticks as - depending on where you live - some of the diseases they might carry can spread from contact with their mouths, so make sure to wash hands afterwards.

To get rid of the ticks I usually wrap them by folding a sticky note, glueing the end together, then squishing the tick with the back of the flea comb and disposing it in the bin. Bigger ones we put on a stone tile and burn them with a hand igniter. I usually don't want to hurt any living being - not even mosquitoes - but for ticks I make an exception.

Comment: Thank you, Related [Tick removal, to twist or not twist?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/tick-removal-to-twist-or-not-twist)